# What does the ? mean in the tokenization section of the W3C CSS specification?

Tags: unicode, grammar, lex, css

Ever since my awful experience with cssparser, I have set myself the task of implementing a CSS parser in Java using [Parboiled](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled). I already have all color specification covered, but of course I need all the rest...

So, I went to look for the CSS specification and found it on the [W3C website](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cover.html). I am now in the process of writing rules for all "atoms", but found something disturbing in [this section](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#tokenization):

```
UNICODE-RANGE   u\+[0-9a-f?]{1,6}(-[0-9a-f]{1,6})?
```

The part that disturbs me is the question mark in `[0-9a-f?]`.

The paragraph heading says the regular expressions used here are Lex-style. The `?` has no special meaning in a character class (thanks @scizzo for the confirmation). So, is this a typo in the W3C specification, or is `?` really allowed in a Unicode range? If yes, what does it mean?

**Wrap up**: I have my answer. However, the specification *is* wrong: a "question mark unicode range" can only be by itself. Given the above regex, this expression would be allowed whereas it is clearly illegal: `u+4??-733f`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, that's a literal question mark. [From the Flex documentation](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/flex/manpage.html):

> Note that inside of a character class, all regular expression operators lose their special  meaning  except  escape
>   ('\') and the character class operators, '-', ']', and, at
>   the beginning of the class, '^'.

Now, according to the W3C, [`?` can be used as a kind of wildcard](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#descdef-unicode-range):

> `?` characters imply 'any digit value' (e.g. U+4??)

Comment: This is one thing confirmed, which means the question mark must be somehow legal in a Unicode range... But I cannot find what it means :/